# Android Dynamically Choosing Cities According To The Countries

Tags: android

At some point of my Android app, I need to store user's country and city and write it to Firebase. I know how to do the Firebase stuff.

My question is how to retrieve cities based on the chosen country from the spinner? I am planning to have two spinners for cities and countries but I don't know how to implement this logic.

I wonder if I should hardcode the countries and cities as a string array in the strings.xml file.. (there will be 40 countries at least)

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's not the best solution but you can use this [file.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json)
put it as assets or send request to it.